# Reshaping long format dataframe to wide format according to the number of elements in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe `X` in long format:

```
alt.var group
1       1 
2       1
3       1
4       1
1       2
2       2
1       3
2       3
1       4
1       5
2       5
3       5
1       6
```

And I would like to change to the following wide format according the number of alternatives in the group:

```
group 1  2  3  4
1     4  3  2  1
2     4  3  NA NA
3     4  3  NA NA
4     4  NA NA NA
5     4  3  2  NA
6     4  NA NA NA
```

i.e. I want to create 4 columns (indexed by 1,2,3,4, the names as in the `alt.var` column) (the maximum number of alternatives in a group) and column `i` get assigned `5-i` if element `i` exists in group `i` and `NA` or null value if element `i` does not exists in group `i`.

I have tried to do a little digging in stackoverflow but it doesn't seem to match any result.

Comment: Can you explain the result?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh , Hi, I want to create 4 columns (indexed by 1,2,3,4, the names as in the ```alt.var``` column) (the maximum number of alternatives in a group) and column ```i``` get assigned ```5-i``` if element ```i``` exists in group ```i``` and ```NA``` or null value if element ```i``` does not exists in group ```i```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `val` column with `5` - value in `alt.var` then `pivot`

```py
out = (df.assign(val=5-df['alt.var'])
       .pivot(index='group', columns='alt.var', values='val'))
```

```
print(out)

alt.var    1    2    3    4
group
1        4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0
2        4.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
3        4.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
4        4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
5        4.0  3.0  2.0  NaN
6        4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```